# Is it safe to observe LiveData inside onActivityCreated or onViewCreated

Tags: android, android-livedata

Is it safe to observe `LiveData` inside `onActivityCreated` or `onViewCreated`, isn't it adds new observer to the `LifecycleOwner` and multiple observers will be active in the same `Fragment`?
For example when we navigate from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B` then navigate back to `Fragment A`, `onActivityCreated` \ `onViewCreated` in `Fragment A` will be called **twice** and `viewModel.liveData.observe()` will be called **twice**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on which `Lifecycle` object are you going to pass to your `Observer`.

Let's say you subscribe your `Observer` in `Fragment's` `onCreate` method. This solve the problems with `observe` called twice, but if the user press back button the `Fragment A`'s `onCreate` won't be called so no `Observer` subscribed. Or even in some cases your observe method can be called while your Fragment is now active and leads to crash.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer { myData -> {} });
}
```

The second option you have is to subscribe in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`. The problem with these two options is that it will get called everytime the `Fragment A` gets recreated and at the end you will end up with more than one observers.

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer { myData -> {} });
}
```

So how we can solve those issues? The answer is simple: use `viewLifecycleOwner`.

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { myData -> {} });
}
```

Because in this way you observe your `LiveData` bound to `Fragment` view's lifecycle.

So it is safe to observe `LiveData` in `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` and in `onActivityCreated` since it'se called after `onCreateView` by documentation: [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) (but deprecated in API Level 28 and not encouraged to be used anymore).

P.S. A really helpful talk on this problem in Google IO 2018: [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pErTyQpA390&feature=youtu.be&t=349)

Comment: Okay so `observe` with `viewLifecycleOwner` it safe, but what actually happen? the new observer not added or where is the magic?

Comment: Since your observer is tied to Fragment view's lifecycle, once the view is destroyed, the observer is unsubscribed too. If you recreate the Fragment after that it will add the observer again once the onCreateView method is called.